# IntegrityError user_id may not be NULL

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

this is my forms.py file

```
 def save(self,ip_address, *args, **kwargs):
        g = GeoIP()
        lat,lon = g.lat_lon(ip_address)
        user_location = super(registerForm, self).save()
        user_location.latitude = lat
        user_location.longitude = lon
        user_location.save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and in my views i have

```
def status_set(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        rform = registerForm(data = request.POST)
        if rform.is_valid():
            register = rform.save(ip_address='203.99.178.139')
            register.user=request.user
            register.save(ip_address)
            return render_to_response('home.html')
    else:
        rform = registerForm() 
    return render_to_response('status_set.html',{'rform':rform})
```

but when i try to submit the forms it says "IntegrityError :accounts_register.user_id may not be NULL"but i have                `register.user=request.user`in my views. do i have to pass the "Id" or "PK" as an argument to forms or em i making a mistake

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803789/integrityerror-while-saving-a-new-item-to-the-postgresql-db-in-django/7635773

Answer (score 1):

You are probably dealing with an [AnonymousUser](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#anonymous-users) object and the id will always be set to None.  If you are running `./manage.py runserver`, try using [pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html) by putting in a line like this before the statement that is failing:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

That will kick you into a [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop) where you can step through and explore your code.

Comment: i have checked using import pdb and the code fails after this line register = rform.save(ip_address='203.99.178.139')
do i have to pass it as an argument to forms save method

Comment: I can only answer with perhaps because it all depends on the code in your registerForm.save().  You can [s]tep into your save() subroutine, goto to the [n]ext statement, or [c]ontinue once at the pdb prompt.  Here is a bit of a pdb helper if you have a hard time grokking the pdb docs: http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/category/the-python-debugger/